# How to get text of uitextfields in table view.?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

How to get values of textfields in tableview in ios5? I have tried tags but its not working.

Comment: are you using a static or a dynamic table view?

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you use custom cells.
If you want to get text values when cell become selected (you need to set tag for UITextField when you create it or in xib file):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITextField *textField = [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:1];
    NSSTring *text = textField.text;
}
```

Or you can set delegate to UITextField when you create cell
In

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Set delegate

```
UITextField *textField = [cell viewWithTag:1];
textField.delegate = self;
```

You can read about UITextField delegate [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)